# подскажите что не так с sql запросом

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы:

**competition**

```
competition_id (ID соревнования);
competition_name (наименование соревнования);
world_record (мировой рекорд);
set_date (дата установки мирового рекорда);
```

**result**

```
competition_id (ID соревнования);
sportsman_id (ID спортсмена);
result (результат спортсмена);
city (место проведения);
hold_date (дата проведения);
```

Нужно - вывести города, в которых были установлены мировые рекорды.
Мой запрос:

```
select city 
from result 
inner join competition on result.result < competition.world_record;
```

Ну что-то в нем неправильно, он все города вообще выводит...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select r.city
from competition c
inner join result r on r.competition_id = c.competition_id and 
                       c.world_record = r.result
```

Что не так в вашем запросе. Вы выводите названия городов у которых были результаты меньше чем мировой рекорд

Comment: этот запрос выбивает все города увы

Comment: @RoyFace подправил ответ